# How to get Datas from RFDuino into IOS App

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, rfduino

I want to send 3 bool datas (trigger signals) from the RFDuino to a IOS App.

Following my code of in the RFDuino:

```
#include "RFduinoBLE.h"

int Taster1 = 2;
int Taster2 = 3;
int Taster3 = 4;

int varTaster1 = 0;
int varTaster2 = 0;
int varTaster3 = 0;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  RFduinoBLE.advertisementData = "CouDow"; // shouldnt be more than 10 characters long 
  RFduinoBLE.deviceName = "IONIQ"; // name of your RFduino. Will appear when other BLE enabled devices search for it 
 // RFduinoBLE.customUUID = "c97433f0-be8f-4dc8-b6f0-5343e6100eb4";
  RFduinoBLE.begin(); // begin

  pinMode(Taster1, INPUT);
  pinMode(Taster2, INPUT);
  pinMode(Taster3, INPUT);

}

void loop() {

  varTaster1 = digitalRead(Taster1);
  varTaster2 = digitalRead(Taster2);
  varTaster3 = digitalRead(Taster3);

  Serial.println(varTaster1);
  Serial.println(varTaster2);
  Serial.println(varTaster3);

  RFduinoBLE.send(varTaster1);
  RFduinoBLE.send(varTaster2);
  RFduinoBLE.send(varTaster3);

}
```

My question now ist how to get the datas in IOS (swift)?

I`m already able to connect the RFDuino to my phone.

Thanks!

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include all relevant Swift code that you use to connect.